# How to Insert multiple data to one row as students to one class_room in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am working a E-learning website.
I made students, teachers, courses and class_rooms tables in my database.

The plan is to enter a classroom from dashboard then make a new classroom connected to 1 teacher, 1 course and many students.

I can insert teacher and course by ID , but what about the students?
I tried but failed to make another table and connect everything.

Comment: First of all show us your code. And second, you can use relationships (many to many and hasManyThrough) https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create pivot table kind
`class_room_student`. Here you will store class_room ID and student ID.
 And use relation [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
/**
 * In ClassRoom Model (getting students of class)
 */
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
}


/**
 * In Student Model (getting classes of one student)
 */
public function classes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ClassRoom::class);
}
```

Don't forget about 'pivot table', 'foreign_key', 'other_key' if needed.

Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('class_room_student', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('class_room_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('class_room_id')->references('id')->on('class_rooms')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['student_id', 'class_room_id']);
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('class_room_student');
}
```

Comment: So I should have row for each student in class_room_student? will that make the website heavy?
after the class ends every student will be out until I make the next class, I need to select student manually coz not every student in the same class. is that possible ?

sorry for the long answer, you helped a lot , thanks :)

Comment: It does not make your website heavy and slowly if you will use index. Your datatable entries look like (stud_1 - class_1 | stud_2 - class_1 | stud_2 - calss_2 ...) One stud can belongs to several classes.

Comment: Is not this bad in long term? this will make a lot of data, the class is not a course it wont be the same class always, and I **need** to recreate it every time coz on create the selected names will receive message contain zoom link , so that is why I am lost

Comment: Thanks that edit really helped a lot, but still how to select them from dashboard? the class room model only will need the student_id key right?

Comment: This is the standard solution in such situations. If you set indexes, the application will not slow down, even with tens of thousands of records. You can also delete data if it is not needed.

Comment: I see now, but sorry what do you mean by datatable entries, the column name in db?

Comment: datatable entries = data stored in table

Comment: final question, how to store them as index? it student_id and class_room_id, how can I make them stud_1 - class_1 etc... in the database or in the dashboard? 
or what the columns I need to add in the classroom and student tables?
sorry to bother you.

Comment: I edit my answer. Now you can run migrations and see how table should look like (with index). You do not need to add any colums to other tables. class_room_student - is only pivot table witch binds students and classes.

Comment: Can I ask final question?
How to use the table now? should i enter values when i make new classroom from classroom controller? how to do that? sorry if i am troubling you

Comment: When you need to create o update related data you should  use attach or sync method (see docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships )